# Bootstrap File Input: Tooltips of preview not displayed as normal tooltip

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, file-upload

I'm using [Bootstrap File Input](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input)
. One thing annoying is preview's tooltip on hover is displayed like a floating HTML element instead of a normal tooltip. And this makes my page shaking as its height keeps changing on hover on the previews.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I'm using this approach, just not to display preview's tooltip:

```
$(":file").fileinput({
    layoutTemplates: {
        footer: '<div class="file-thumbnail-footer">\n' +
                '    <div class="file-caption-name" style="width:{width}">{caption}</div>\n' +
                '    {progress} {actions}\n' +
                '</div>'
    },
    previewTemplates: {
        image: '<div class="file-preview-frame" id="{previewId}" data-fileindex="{fileindex}">\n' +
                '   <img src="{data}" class="file-preview-image" alt="{caption}" style="width:{width};height:{height};">\n' +
                '   {footer}\n' +
                '</div>\n'
    }
});
```